# org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: JDBC DatabaseMetaData method in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am working on spring boot -jax-rs rest service. While staring my application I am getting the below error.I am using java 8 with ojdbc 14 installed at class path . please help if any one have any idea.

> 2019-02-25 09:10:21.638  INFO 8360 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet
>   ApplicationConfiguration.App mapped to [/*] 2019-02-25 09:10:22.714 
>   INFO 8360 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
>   : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 2019-02-25 09:10:23.453  INFO 8360 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1
>   - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I) 2019-02-25
>   09:10:23.453 ERROR 8360 --- [  restartedMain]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to
>   execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query
>   (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z). 2019-02-25
>   09:10:23.484  WARN 8360 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc
>   url from datasource
>
> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: JDBC
>   DatabaseMetaData method not implemented by JDBC driver - upgrade your
>   driver; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:333)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:355)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by changing ojdbc14 to ojdbc7